# log_url_info logs the visitor's first url, regardless of page visited

Tags: magento-1.9, log, core-session

The log_url_info table should ideally log every url visited. It seems to work by logging the "request_uri" in the session data for the user. "request_uri" in the session data is not updated, even after adding products to cart. The result is a new duplicate entry into "log_url_info" with every page load for that session.

Has anyone figured out how to fix the url logger so that it logs every url a visitor loads, not just the first?

Each of these url's should be different:
[image: same url]

UPDATE:
I tried this in an ultra vanilla install of 1.9.3.0, with the only change being a switch from "Visitors only" to "Yes" in `System -> Configuration -> System -> Log -> Enable Log` same issue! Which confirms it's either a misconfiguration or a Magento bug.

Answer (score 0):

URL logging is a little half baked and is left over from the days before Analytics became what it is. To make the logger save every URL you'll need to modify `Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php` (preferably as a local override) and insert `$this->setRequestUri($this->_httpHelper->getRequestUri(true));` after `$this->setLastVisitAt(now());` in `saveByRequest`.

Once all is set and done it should look like this on 1.9.3.0

```
public function saveByRequest($observer)
{
    if ($this->_skipRequestLogging || $this->isModuleIgnored($observer))                                                    {
        return $this;
    }

    try {
        $this->setLastVisitAt(now());
        $this->setRequestUri($this->_httpHelper->getRequestUri(true));
        $this->save();
        $this->_session->setVisitorData($this->getData());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    return $this;
}
```